# rack-offline gem : where is the resulting manifest file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using 'rack-offline' gem to manage the HTML5 manifest

I installed it, configured and run the app wo error , but it's not so clear on how to relate it to the HTML manifest , and to the current Rails app :

- match "/application.manifest" => Rails::Offline  in routes.. is it AS IT or application should be the name of the Rails app... ?  i.e.    match "/workshop.manifest" => Rails::Offline

I don't see the manifest attribute  in the generated html :

- should we add a  MIME-type, "text/cache-manifest" in the mime_types.rb initializer ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the missing info are the following  ( after adding the gem, and setting the config as an initializer file  rack_offline.rb

in routes : I inserted the path

```
match "/application.manifest" => Rails::Offline, :as => :manifest
```

In my application layout ( haml) I modified the html tag

```
%html{:lang => "en", :manifest => manifest_path }
# which generates the following html .. ( I have localized routes ... )
<html lang='en' manifest='/fr/application.manifest'>
```

In my config/initializers/mime_types.rb, I added
    Mime::Type.register "text/cache-manifest", :manifest

Then restarting the server, I can see in the log :
    Started GET "/fr/application.manifest" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-25 11:26:40 +0100

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# aba331a67ba974bf70c665dfc48a1bea5da7d8fe352c46a76af07f45c339d422
404.html
422.html
500.html
offline.html

NETWORK:
*
```

these are all the html files in public ... 
need to understand and check if it's a correctly generated manifest file